# Unity Ads. Is the Ad.show placementId parameter used anymore?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ads

I started a project a long time ago with the Unity ad api v1, now that they have moved onto Advert api v2 i'm wondering if they still use the placementId parameter.

I'm only wondering this because they used to support video and image based Ads. As far as I know they only do video now. They used to have examples similar to this:

```
Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideo", options);
```

Which specified which of the supported advert types you want, `rewardedVideo` for video and `rewardedImage` (or something similar) for images.

With the loss of images and the integration guide (behind the login screen) having been changed **does the palcementId parameter still matter since I noticed that you can pass in only the callback stuff?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does matter. if you pass placementId "video" then ad is skippable if you pass "rewardedVideo" then ad is not skippable. Tested this in unity ads 2.0.8

Comment: Oh cool, makes me wonder why they don't just use an enum but still